# Operating on multiple lists?

Tags: elisp

On page 224 of [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/) this example is given with the output.

```
> (mapcar #'(lambda (x y) (list x 'gets y))
     '(fred wilma george diane)
     '(job1 job2 job3 job4))

((FRED GETS JOB1)
(WILMA GETS JOB2) 
(GEORGE GETS JOB3)
(DIANE GETS JOB4))
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in Emacs Lisp?  The other example is also interesting because only 3 results, the number of elements in the shortest list, are produced.

```
> (mapcar #'+ '(1 2 3) '(10 20 30 40 50))
(11 22 33)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping a function over two lists in elisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028696/mapping-a-function-over-two-lists-in-elisp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs has `mapcar*` in the `cl` package which does exactly that. Here is the documentation:

> Apply FUNCTION to each element of SEQ, and make a list of the results.
>   If there are several SEQs, FUNCTION is called with that many arguments,
>   and mapping stops as soon as the shortest list runs out. With just one
>   SEQ, this is like `mapcar`.  With several, it is like the Common Lisp
>   `mapcar` function extended to arbitrary sequence types.