# Mapping a function over two lists in elisp

Tags: lisp, elisp

In common lisp I can do this:

```lisp
(mapcar #'cons '(1 2 3) '(a b c))

=> ((1 . A) (2 . B) (3 . C))
```

How do I do the same thing in elisp? When I try, I get an error:

```
(wrong-number-of-arguments mapcar 3)
```

If elisp's mapcar can only work on one list at a time, what is the idomatic way to combine two lists into an alist?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want `mapcar*`, which accepts one or more sequences (not just lists as in Common Lisp), and for one sequence argument works just like the regular `mapcar`.

```
(mapcar* #'cons '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
((1 . A) (2 . B) (3 . C))
```

And even if it weren’t defined, you could easily roll your own:

```
(defun mapcar* (f &rest xs)
  "MAPCAR for multiple sequences"
  (if (not (memq nil xs))
    (cons (apply f (mapcar 'car xs))
      (apply 'mapcar* f (mapcar 'cdr xs)))))
```

Comment: Since it's part of cl-macs, you should call it as `cl-mapcar` and make sure to `(require 'cl-lib)`.

Answer (score 18):

Emacs has built-in [Common Lisp library](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/), which introduces plenty of Common Lisp functions and macros, but with the `cl-` prefix. There is no reason to avoid this library. `cl-mapcar` is what you want:

```
(cl-mapcar '+ '(1 2 3) '(10 20 30)) ; (11 22 33)
```

With [**`dash`**](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list manipulation library (see the [installation instructions](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#installation)), you can use [`-zip-with`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-zip-with-fn-list1-list2) (remember: `-zip-with` is the same as `cl-mapcar` applied to 2 lists):

```
(-zip-with '+ '(1 2 3) '(10 20 30)) ; (11 22 33)
```

I don't know an elegant way to implement a `-zip-with` equivalent for 3 arguments. But you may use [`-partial`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-partial-fn-rest-args) from **`dash-functional`** package, which comes with **`dash`** (functions from **`dash-functional`** require Emacs 24). `-partial` partially applies the function, so these 2 function invocations below are equivalent:

```
(-zip-with '+ '(1 2) '(10 20)) ; (11 22)
(funcall (-partial '-zip-with '+) '(1 2) '(10 20)) ; (11 22)
```

Then, you can use it with a [`-reduce`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-reduce-fn-list) function:

```
(-reduce (-partial '-zip-with '+) '((1 2 3) (10 20 30) (100 200 300))) 
; (111 222 333)
```

You can wrap it into a function with `&rest` keyword, so this function would accept varying amount of arguments instead of a list:

```
(defun -map* (&rest lists)
  (-reduce (-partial 'zip-with '+) lists))
```